# How can I change a parameter in a function that is in a package?

Tags: r

I'm working with the package "survPresmooth" and I want to change control.presmooth$n.boot from c(5000, 1000) to c(1000, 200) is there any way I can do this?

I tried

```
control.presmooth$n.boot <- c(1000, 200)
```

but it didn't work because

> object of type 'closure' is not subset

I also tried to edit the control.presmooth function with

```
trace(control.presmooth, edit = TRUE)
```

but it returned this error:

> Error in .makeTracedFunction(def, tracer, exit, at, print, doEdit) :
> the editing in trace() can only change the body of the function, not
> the arguments or defaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `?preSmooth`: I think the correct way to change the parameters is like this:

`presmooth([...], control = control.presmooth(n.boot = c(1000, 200)))`

That means that you have to specify the `control` parameter of the `presmooth()` function. The value you have to specify for this parameter is the `control.presmooth()` function. This is how many control functions work in R.